# How to limit paper size to number of rows in c# excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I want to limit page size to 30 rows and rest of the data start from next page in excel. Currently it is set to **Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4**. I tried page break with a condition

```
 if (row_no >= 30)
 {
 rng = (Excel.Range)xl_sheet.Range[xl_sheet.Cells[row_no, 1],xl_sheet.Cells[row_no, 1]];
 xl_sheet.HPageBreaks.Add(rng);
 row_no = 12;
 }
```

but the code above did not start from next page.

My code for page setup:

```
        xl_sheet.Select(Type.Missing);
        var ps = xl_sheet.PageSetup;
        ps.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
        ps.FitToPagesTall = false;
        ps.FitToPagesWide = 1;
        ps.Zoom = false;
        ps.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4;
        ps.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$11";
```

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful? Especially the worksheet.Range[] part? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408492/getting-maximum-row-column-number-from-excel-range

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to page break and next page should start from row number 12 when it reaches row number 30 it should page break in the loop. I'm iterating data in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue using following code and it working fine:

```
if (row_no% 30==0)
 {
 rng = (Excel.Range)xl_sheet.Range[xl_sheet.Cells[row_no, 1],xl_sheet.Cells[row_no, 1]];
 xl_sheet.HPageBreaks.Add(rng);

 }
```